# How to include symbol in a string

Tags: swift2, swift3

Been searching for including symbol in a string in swift. can you help how to convert this Obj-c syntax to Swift.

```
Symbol like Copyright, degree and others useful symbols.

[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Copyright \u00A9 2016"]

this does not work
let strMessage: NSString = "@"Copyright \u00A9 2016"
```

Thanks

Comment: Better read [this part](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID293) of the Swift book carefully..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just do this:

```
let strMessage = "Copyright \u{00A9} 2016"
```

Comment: let strMessage: NSString = "copyright  \u{00A9} 2016"  +  (concatenate other string type message) . This work for me. But will this in anyway violate NSString?

Comment: @MilkBottle why are you trying to use NSString instead of just a swift string?

Comment: The reason: I enter  symbol, smiley and other characters from Keyboard into a textView and I need to pass textView.text to another Receiving ViewController in which I use NSString to receive it and use it with attributed string.

Comment: Is there a diff between using NSString and String in my case for passing it to Receiving ViewController?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the copyright symbol directly by holding alt/option and hitting g.

just input that as part of your string

var strMessage = "Copyright © 2016"

Comment: Degrees symbol is Alt+k